# Is it okay to reload interstitial ad onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()?

Tags: java, android, admob

```
private void requestNewInterstitial(int max) {
    if (!adIsLoading && mInterstitialAd == null) {
        adIsLoading = true;

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        InterstitialAd.load(FirstActivity.this, getString(R.string.inter)),
                adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        adIsLoading = false;


                        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                mInterstitialAd = null;
                                requestNewInterstitial(5);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                                mInterstitialAd = null;
                            }


                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                            mInterstitialAd = null;
                            adIsLoading = false;
                        if (maxretry > 0) {
                            requestNewInterstitial(maxretry - 1);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    else{
        mInterstitialAd = null;

    }
}
```

You can see how in the method onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() I am requesting a new interstitial again in the line of code: `requestNewInterstitial(5);`. It seems to be working, but I want to know if this is totally okay or this is against any admob rule ore something like that? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is OK, but do not show the second Ad after the first one immediately, but rather show it after another action.